# How to check if my current window is the top most visible window

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a window which is set to AlwaysOnTop using the WS_EX_TOPMOST flag. Now, it is possible that some other application might also have a window which has WS_EX_TOPMOST set and override the topmost flag for my window.

How should I check if my window is indeed the window that is the top most window and nothing is being painted over it (the nothing is being painted over my window is the important part). If something is painting over my window, I want to hide my window and show it again when I can make it the top most window (but that's probably the second step)

Comment: Marked as "unclear what you're asking"

Comment: I would definitely not want that from any application I'm using...

Comment: @duDE Weird. You answered this question with a copy-pasted answer and then deleted to mark this question as unclear?

Comment: @duDE http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/269140/How-to-determine-if-your-window-is-topmost

Comment: @MatsPetersson Why is that so? The application just want to know if something else is painting over it. If yes, I just want to get back to being the top most window.

Comment: @TheBlueNotebook The fun starts when two windows take that stance.

Comment: Or when you don't want that application to be on top of another window, for whatever reason...

Comment: @MatsPetersson Understandable. But could I still be helped with the engineering aspects of this? Let's just say, I want to see what is this fun you speak of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call [`GetWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633515.aspx) passing your topmost window's handle and the `GW_HWNDFIRST` flag. The window returned will be the topmost window that is highest in the Z-order. You can then use the `GW_HWNDNEXT` flag to walk through the topmost windows in order of decreasing Z-order until you find yours. If any of the windows overlap your window, then your window is underneath.

Comment: OK, anyone know what I got wrong here, or is this just bitter revenge?

Comment: Sounds like bitter revenge. Happened with me as well.

Comment: Also, can you please elaborate on this? I used GetWindow with my window's handle and the FW_HWNDFIRST flag and I get some other window, even though my window is the top most visible window. I didn't quite get why you suggested to iterate though all the topmost windows after finding the topmost window that is highest in the Z-order?

Comment: You iterate because there could be multiple windows above your window in the Z-order.

Comment: So your point is that if there are multiple windows above my window in Z-order, my window is not top most, right?

Comment: There could be multiple windows above yours, that overlap, or multiple windows above yours that do not overlap.

Comment: This solves only part of the question. A complete answer also needs [GetWindowRect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633519.aspx), [IntersectRect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145001.aspx), and [IsRectEmpty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145017.aspx).

Comment: @IInspectable I rather imagined that the asker would be able to work out that part and that the issue was with the Z-order

Comment: *"How should I check if my window is indeed the window that is the top most window and **nothing is being painted over it**"* - this doesn't seem to imply, that the second part is known. It becomes even more involved when accounting for drop shadows of other windows (in case that's required). Besides, answers on SO should be complete. *"You can work out the rest"* is not generally useful.

Comment: @IInspectable I find these exchanges with you somewhat tiresome. The asker accepted my answer. I think that this means that the asker can work out the rest. In any answer, one needs to decide the level at which to pitch it. I mean, where do I stop? Do I need to teach the asker how to iterate? How to check return values for errors? How to declare variables? How to compile the program? I drew the line at a place other than you would.

Comment: There's no need for the hostility. The fact, that the asker accepted your answer does not invalidate my previous statement: Answers should be generally useful. That includes future visitors. As posted, this answer only addresses part of the question.

Comment: @IInspectable There is indeed no need for any hostility.

Comment: Great. So why not leave out the personal attacks in the future? I critiqued your answer purely on a technical level, until your *"I find these exchanges with you somewhat tiresome"* came out of the blue. If you don't feel like improving an answer, there's little I can do about it, other than voicing my opinion. I can, however, expect to be treated with all due respect.

Comment: @IInspectable I suppose that I have grown weary of your comments on this site, and for once I was not able to contain my frustration.

Answer (score 3):

The old standard way was to call WindowFromPoint for a point on your supposedly visible window and compare the returned handle against your own window handle. There is a better way using the clipping system. I discuss this [here](http://bobmoore.mvps.org/Win32/w32tip72.htm).

Comment: I used the central point in the window client area... until I gave up and used the clipping method, which is better because it gives you information about partially visible windows rather than just a yes/no. The real problem with the WindowFromPoint method is that it doesn't work for disabled windows.

Comment: The IsWindowVisibleToUser function always returns IWVTU_PARTIAL
regardless of whether the windows are hidden in the back or front.